# Can you post git tags with tfs

Tags: git, rest, post, tfs

I'm currently working on a project where I need to POST git tags using the TFS Rest API. I am limited to using the API version 2.0, which has no documentation for how I can POST a tag, however the functionality must be there as the response code does not indicate that a POST is not possible. My request looks something like this.

```
POST {root_url}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/refs?api-version=2.0"
{
   "name": "refs/tags/test",
   "objectId": "{commitId}"
}
```

The error that I get is as follows:

> {
>   "$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: refUpdates","typeName":"System.Argu
>   mentNullException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","typeKey":"ArgumentNullE
>   xception","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
>   The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I'm not too sure if it's even possible to POST a tag but given the error it should be. Does anyone know how to create a tag using POST or know where I can find documentation for it?

Comment: POST as in create with an API call? How about [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/annotatedtags)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noted that the REST API you posted is used to [Modify one or more refs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/refs#modify-one-or-more-refs) but not add a git tag.

I can reproduce your issue when use the REST API you posted above （See below screenshot for your reference）.

So, to create a tag you need to use the correct REST API :[create annotated tag with the REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/annotatedtags#create-annotated-tag)

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/annotatedTags?api-version={version}
```

I can create the tag correctly with `api-version=3.2-preview.1`

eg:

```
POST http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/feb1793b-4d91-4be4-8373-02216ec5c36b/_apis/git/repositories/ee76df2b-7c31-484e-ad3a-1a21e6b43cfc/annotatedTags?api-version=3.2-preview.1

Content-Type: application/json

{"name":"3344","message":"test1020","taggedObjectId":"ee26491f1919a9afc9181c00a259bf689afced28"}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you are using TFS 2015 or earlier version, then it's not supported, you can use [`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) command to do that.

So, if the REST API is the only option, the solution is that you have to upgrade to TFS 2017 or later version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned, unfortunately I am limited to api version 2.0, this feature is not available to me for the moment. This causes a 404 not found error. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @jacmurphy50 Which version of TFS are you using? if you are using TFS 2015 or earlier version, then it's not supported, you can use [`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) command to do that.

Comment: @jacmurphy50 I can reproduce your issue when use the REST API you posted above. It's not the correct REST API to add a git tag, Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes I believe we are using TFS 2015, looking to upgrade but that could be next year, as you say you can use `git tag`. I tried this approach, however it caused other issues with our Jenkins pipeline. So the REST API is really our only option. So I think maybe we just need to wait to upgrade.

Comment: @jacmurphy50 Yeah, If the REST API is the only option, then you have to upgrade to TFS 2017 or later version.

Comment: @jacmurphy50 I have updated the answer based on the discussion here, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.